# Can one form an adverb from any adjective?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, derivational-morphology

I'm trying to form the following sentence:

> ...we can talk more *substantiatively* in the event that X occurs.

The term "substantiatively" isn't in either the computer dictionary or [online at m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substantiatively). However, it seems to me that if something can be substantiative, then something can be done substantiatively. More generally, if something can be described as <adjective>, then one can do it <adverb form of adjective>. Is that assertion incorrect?

Comment: In general, yes, although there are many exceptions, e.g. determiners. By the way, I have never heard of *substantiative*. Perhaps you mean *substantial* or *substantive* (less likely)?

Comment: @Cerberus - I'm just going off [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substantiate). I won't rule out the possibility that I'm just making stuff up. That's within the realm of possibilisnosity.

Comment: @Cerberus: Coleridge seems to have loved the word _substantiative_. From his [_Notebooks: 1827–1834_](https://books.google.com/books?id=HMsLAQAAIAAJ&q=%22this+not+being+drawn+from+the+Sense+or+the+Senses%22&dq=%22this+not+being+drawn+from+the+Sense+or+the+Senses%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJifGY7afLAhVL5WMKHbRrBhYQ6AEIIzAB): "By the conception of SUBSTANCE ingenerated a priori, i.e. by the influence of Reason the Mediate Faculty becomes Understanding, i.e. **substantiative**, substituent—; but this not being drawn from the Sense or the Senses (= Sense + Sensation or ..."

Comment: ..but a number of the matches for _substantiative_ in Google Books search results are clearly typographical errors or misstatements of _substantive_, as in a law text that refers to "substantiative due process" ("substantive due process" is a very familiar set phrase in U.S. law).

Comment: @Cerberus I don't think that many see determiners/determinatives as being in the class of adjectives. Some dictionaries haven't caught up with accepted classification yet.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: If you don't mind my saying, is it fair to call all of those exceptions? I'd also classify words like *many* and *all* as adjectives.

Comment: Some exceptions would seem to be (though I've not checked in OED): (a) some identity adjectives: same, other / (b) some ordinal adjectives: preceding, further / (c) some degree adjectives (?): outright (d) some temporal adjectives: future, then [past, now? once?] / (e) other adjectives referring to how assembled (or envisaged-as-a-set) referents co-relate: assorted (?), fellow / (f) adjectives of potential / lack of (etc) ...: budding, would-be, wannabe, manqué / (g) modal and veridical (including privative) adjectives: fake.

Comment: (a) Yes; you are right: not all of these examples resist agglutination. I'm assuming OP means other than zero conversion (or rather the existence of a categorial polyseme) by 'form an adverb from [an] adjective'. Obviously, 'outright' and 'further' double as adverbs. However, 'disparately' and 'diversely' obviously exist. Sloppy of me. // (b) Regard 'many' and 'all' as adjectives? Very few (if any) grammarians do nowadays: See [John Lawler's post here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159192/determiner-vs-determinative/159234#159234) (and many others).

Comment: ... And (@Cerberus) this article at [Bright Hub](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/esl-lesson-plans/37875-difference-between-determiners-and-adjectives/).

Comment: Some apparent exceptions to the rule that you can form an adverb from an adjective are due to miscategorizing things as adjectives just because they can be noun modifiers.  You can have "the above examples" and not *"abovely", but that's because "above" is actually a preposition.  You can have "the sleeping child" and not *"sleepingly", but that is because "sleeping" is actually a verb in the participle form.

Comment: There are some cases where it gets kind of silly:  Pope Paul performed mass more holily than did Pope John.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are so many blocked cases here that I feel like we need a real expert. Why can an alert listener listen alertly but an awake one not listen *awakely? Why can a bigger idea not be expressed *biggerly?

Comment: @GregLee Zero derivation works for inside jobs being done inside, but there are so many classes of adjectives blocked from *-ly* derivation to adverbs that I struggle to come up with an overarching “rule” to describe these.

Comment: @tchrist [This article, Katamba F. (1993): Productivity in Word-Formation.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-349-22851-5_4), obviously addressed the views on the accepted limits on productiveness (and how they were then changing), but I can't access all of it. I haven't found an article addressing the reasons so many potentially derived adverbs are absent from the lexicon (though this might). Though apparently, ...

Comment: in [Khwarshi](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qpClCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA3717&lpg=PA3717&dq=forming+adverbs+from+adjectives+productive&source=bl&ots=jM_BqMt0AB&sig=NP3_FAEvBOiQ1MOMQQOdbjvP05Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOje6gjrLVAhWoKsAKHZkXAz8Q6AEISTAH#v=onepage&q=forming%20adverbs%20from%20adjectives%20productive&f=false) 'there are no productive ways to form adverbs'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the original question should be about talking more ***substantively***. The other looks like a misprint to me. The OED attests these *substa-* adverbs:

> substantially [adv.]
>    † substanˈtifically [adv.] ← substanˈtific
>    † subˈstantiously [adv.]
>   substanˈtivally [adv.] ← substantival
>   substantively [adv.]

---

In general, there are ***many*** words that modern grammars classify as adjectives (rather than as determiners or various other noun modifiers) which you cannot convert into adverbs merely by suffixing them with *-ly* via derivational morphology.

Here are some examples of things that don’t work out when you try to do that with them:

- You can look for an **only** son, but you can’t ***onlily** find him.
- An **alert** listener listens alertly, but an **awake** one cannot listen ***awakely**.
- A **bigger** idea can never be expressed ***biggerly**.
- Although **secret** plans can be divulged **secretly**, **small** plans cannot be made ***smally**.
- You can interview an **old**, **white**, **European** man, but you can interview him neither ***oldly** nor ***whitely** nor ***Europeanly**.
- If the judge gave you a **deferred** sentence, you still haven’t been sentenced ***deferredly**.
- People who like **twice-baked** potatoes don’t cook ***twice-bakedly**.
- Just because you find yourself blessed with kittens **galore** doesn’t mean you’ve been ***galorely** blessed.
- If you went looking for men who were **awake**, such men could not be ***awakely** found.
- People who support their **home** teams are not ***homely** supporting those teams. And **homely** people are something else altogether.
- **Homing** pigeons are not just pigeons flown ***homingly**.
- If the position required a professor **emeritus**, it could not be filled ***emeritusly**.
- A daily gardening column is not a column published ***daylily**, only one published **daily** — even if it happens to be about [daylilies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylily). :)
- Although you can extract **bodily** fluids, you cannot extract them ***bodilily**.

The only adjectives you can convert into adverbs by affixing *-ly* to them are those that fit into the pattern:

> in an **<sub><sup>ADJECTIVE</sup></sub>** manner

Those ones you can derive adverbs of manner out of via *-ly*. The rest you cannot.

(Notice how this rules out adjectives that can occur only postnominally, such as *galore*.)

And even some fitting that pattern are normally blocked for other reason; most people aren’t comfortable with converting *-ly* adjectives into *-lily* adverbs.

Comment: OP's general question seems to be answered, but specifically can substantiative be made into an adverb? Would it become an adverb of manner?

Comment: @Zan700 The question was about modifiers not about substantives. To derive an adverb from a substantive like a noun sometimes(?) requires that it first be converted into an adjective. Throwing a ball "like a girl" would be throwing it girlishly not girly or gurlily. There's a good reason that prepositions exist in the language: too much derivation sounds bad, and sometimes any derivation at all is too much.

Comment: @Zan700 Usage trumps patterning that one might expect. Productivity, as has been stated before, is a gradable feature of English. Asking 'Can _substantiative_ be made into an adverb?' is like asking 'Can I verb _idiosyncrasy_?' Dictionaries (or rather the combined output of respected dictionaries, particularly OED) show (to a first approximation) what is in the lexicon. 'Will I get away with 'alright' / 'alot' / 'irregardless' / 'contrafibularities' / 'fluddle' / 'dord' / 'schnabbertift' ...?' Well, who's doing the judging, and why do you want to?

Comment: @Tchrist I wasn't referring to substantives but to substantiative, the word that according to Sven is defined (at least by Coleridge) "By the conception of SUBSTANCE ingenerated a priori . . ." Edwin notes that "Usage trumps patterning that one might expect," Fine. But whether or not substantiatively was ever used, is substantiative one of  "Those ones you can derive adverbs of manner out of via -ly.?"

Comment: @Zan700 I don't know of any *XXX-ive* adjectives that resist manner-adverbial derivation via *-ly* using the *in an XXX-ive manner* “rule”.

Comment: @Edwin If I come across gnxp in an English text, I know immediately it's not an English word because it contains no vowels. If I come across captively, I might not immediately rule it out as an adverb because I know captive is an accepted adjective that ends in ive, so could take an ly. But I would then have to consider if it could somehow be "an adverb of manner." Knowing the definition of captive as an adjective, I can't grasp the word as "an adverb of manner," so I would rule it out as adverb in the English lexicon before consulting the OED.

Comment: @Zan700 Your rule is incorrect according to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_words_without_vowels) and all other  treatments I'm aware of. Hm / hmm / sh / brrr (but not shh). 'Rules' we like to trot out are often pseudo-rules, guidelines with varying numbers of exceptions. // I can grasp a manner meaning for 'captively' if it existed (and Wikipedia and almost 200 000 hits on the internet strongly suggest it does). ?'Their attention was hardly held captively.' (The depictive construction 'held captive' is normal, of course.)

Comment: 'Recently' is from 'recent', which seems to be an exception to 'The only adjectives you can convert into adverbs by affixing -ly to them are those that fit into the pattern: "in an ADJECTIVE manner" '. As does frequency adverb 'rarely' from 'rare'. (I assume you're including past conversions.)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer. It does beg the question of what difference exists between the two types of adjectives you mention (those that work as "...in a XX manner" and those that don't). I'd be curious if this is formalized in grammar or if it's just another idiosyncrasy of the English language.

Comment: @Edwin: Nor my rule exactly. That Wikipedia article continues on to say, "That  In most languages of the world, all or nearly all lexical words have vowel sounds, and English is no exception." It's hardly a surprise that "rules," or even "pseudo-rules" have exceptions. Try it with "motive."

Comment: @Zan700 You claim to use the rule; you cite the rule as if it's gospel: it's acceptable to call it 'your rule'. // What I'm pointing out is that 'If I come across _____ in an English text, I know immediately it's not an English word because it contains no vowels.' is incorrect because some English words contain _no_ vowels. // _Usage trumps patterning that one might expect_ means that the correct thing to do is to look in OED etc for proof of lexicality. If a word is not listed there (and not in ODO, AHD, Collins ...), this does not mean it isn't in the lexis. But you can't just assume ...

Comment: that it _is_. Wordness is notoriously difficult to define (are two mentions in reliable periodicals etc enough for a candidate to qualify? Two hundred? Which periodicals etc are 'reliable'? Does an obsolete label in OED remove a word from the lexis?) But whether or not an affix may be used in a specific conversion is determined by whether the new candidate word is accepted into the lexis, not by how many times the process has worked in the past.

Comment: @Edwin A rhetorical convenience. So the judges you earlier referred to are those that accept the "new candidate word" into the lexis?

Comment: @Zan700 I was referring to the people at the pub/club, who might stop talking to you. The teachers who might mark you down. The interview board that might choose the other candidate. The editor who might fire you.... 'Can I make a new word by applying this 'rule' that seems to work some of the time?' We don't even agree on what 'word' means on ELU. // Live funly.

Comment: @Edwin Ah, that old bête noire, the world.

Comment: @Zan This _is_ called _English Language and Usage_.

Answer (score -1):

There is no rule that any adjective can form an adverb, however there seem to be few that have not done so at least once in literature, so could be regarded as "legitimate".

Comment: *Long* in the context of time can be replaced with *slowly*.

Comment: Easy can be turned into an adverb--easily

Comment: *Redly*, *longly*, and *complexly* all appear both in dictionaries and in the wild.

Comment: I removed "long" from the examples I gave because as with many adjectives it is an adverb too, without change of spelling.

Comment: On the other hand, the adjective _rewritten_, as in "a rewritten essay," doesn't yield an adverbial form that I've ever seen used.

Comment: Certainly [complexly](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=complexly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomplexly%3B%2Cc0) is legitimate.

Comment: I have removed complexly as an example, as although it is extremely rare it is legitimate.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer because my examples of adjectives which do not form adverbs have all turned out to be "legitimate".  In my original answer I was thinking of common usage rather than legitimacy. I now know I was wrong.

Comment: @ArtOfCode: True, but you're inherently rephrasing by switching to the adverb. You wouldn't have said that "the passage of time was long", so you wouldn't be trying to say that "time passed longly" in the first place. There's no connection between slowly as an adverb, and long as an adjective. Unless I'm glossing over a case that does not rephrase the entire sentence?