# Category of the First Term in the Partitive Construction

Tags: parts-of-speech, determiners

Are the words in bold type in the following sentences determiners?

1. **One** of the books was written by X
2. I want **two** of those
3. **8 percent** of the population has X
4. I ate **some** of that cake

In a treatise on partitives, the author identifies them as *determiners*. But I don't see a noun following these 'determiners'. Without a following noun, they more resemble a pronoun referring to that absent noun.

Online Oxford Dictionary defines *partitive* as:

> 1. A partitive construction
>      1.1. A noun or pronoun used as the first term in a partitive construction

From the definition it seems that the first term, which I think is the word or a group of words before ***of***, is either a noun or a pronoun.

Comment: They are quantifiers functioning as determinatives. They are not determiners. (Of course, that depends on which grammar you consult, because [they are not consistent in their terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159192/determiner-vs-determinative).)

Comment: Some theories consider quantifiers as determiners, along with articles and demonstratives.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to consider polysemous words:

1) as several parts-of-speech that must be disambiguated by context.

2) as new parts-of-speech that share properties of multiple existing POS.

3) as single parts-of-speech that occur with other POS elided for brevity.

By method (3) they are **determiners**:

One [book] of the books ...

I want two [things] of those [things].

8 [people] per_cent=one_hundred [people] of the population=people ...

I ate some [cake/part] of that [one] cake.